# Run SQL script from ASP.Net C# application performance issue

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I'm running SQL script from C# code, my problem that the code take a long time to finish execution, it has many tables to be created in script(at least 30 Tables), so my code is working but it has performance issue.
this is the code

```
public static bool executeSqlScript(string scriptPath,string serverName,string databaseName)
    {
        try
        {

            SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection("Server=.;Integrated security=SSPI;database=master");
            Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(myConn));
            string CreateCommand = "CREATE DATABASE " + databaseName + "";
            string appendText;
            //delete first line from script(Oldscript)
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(scriptPath).Skip(1);
            File.WriteAllLines(scriptPath, lines);
            using (StreamReader sreader = new StreamReader(scriptPath))
            {
                appendText = sreader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            File.Delete(scriptPath);
            using (StreamWriter swriter = new StreamWriter(scriptPath, false))
            {
                appendText = "USE [" + databaseName + "]" + Environment.NewLine + appendText;
                swriter.Write(appendText);
                swriter.Close();
            }
            string readtext = File.ReadAllText(scriptPath);
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(CreateCommand, myConn);
            myConn.Open();
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(readtext);

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
         throw e;
         return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please paste the code into your question body.

Comment: How often do you need to create these tables? Is it something that you could do in parallel instead of serial?

Comment: What do you mean by serial?

Comment: Meaning that you're creating one, then creating another, then creating another. I also see that you're creating a database, it's possible that that's what's slowing it down.

Comment: ok, could you please provide the code for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in Go Keyword in script, I Found this solution

http://www.codingdefined.com/2014/07/run-sql-script-file-in-c.html

(If you are trying to execute a SQL generated script file you have to remove all "GO". For that you have to use the following code...)

Here is my code:

```
        string sqlConnectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True";
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(@"D:\Script.sql");
        string script = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        script = script.Replace("GO", "");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(script, conn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Dispose();
        conn.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to migrate most of this to the SQL Server, once the new DB and User are setup, call a Stored Procedure to read the SQL file with the necessary DDL in it.

My last project was for a managed hosting company, and our CMS utilized well over 150 database objects. We used a "control" database which we pass in the new DB information and it would ceate the new tables, functions, and procedures generally in less than a minute.

Comment: Could you please give me an example for this approach?

Comment: Can't give you specifics, but [Sql Server Central](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic452984-146-1.aspx) has a forum discussion which may guide you

Answer (score 0):

use Parallel.ForEach to create tables likes

```
public static bool executeSqlScript(string scriptPath, string serverName, string databaseName)
    {
        try
        {

            SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection("Server=.;Integrated security=SSPI;database=master");
            //Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(myConn));
            string CreateCommand = "CREATE DATABASE " + databaseName + "";
            string appendText;
            //delete first line from script(Oldscript)
            //create db first
            var myCommand = new SqlCommand(CreateCommand, myConn);
            myConn.Open();
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            myConn.Close();


            List<string[]> list = File.ReadLines(scriptPath)
                .Select(line => line.ToLower().Split(new string[] { "go" }, StringSplitOptions.None))
                .ToList();
            Parallel.ForEach(list, (sql) =>
            {
                using (var mysqlConn = new SqlConnection("Server=.;Integrated security=SSPI;database=master"))
                {
                    var mysql = "USE [" + databaseName + "]" + Environment.NewLine + string.Join("", sql);
                    var mysqlCommand = new SqlCommand(mysql, mysqlConn);
                    myConn.Open();
                    mysqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            });

            //server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(readtext);

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
            return false;
        }
    }
```